# Getting Portrait mode's height and width when the orientation is Landscape in OrientationEventListener in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-orientation

I want to get the screen height and width when the device's orientation changes and I'm using [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener) instead of the onConfigurationChanged() method.

For the below Code:

1)OrientationEventListener

```
mOrientationListener = object : OrientationEventListener (context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
{
override fun onOrientationChanged (orientation: Int)
{
    if (gTemp == false) {
        
        gTemp = true
    
    } else if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {

        Log.d ("orientation", "Orientation: Portrait")
        
        height = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenHeight ()
        width = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenWidth ()
         
        // call cpp function 
        OrientationChanged (pInstructionSetIndex, width, height)


    } else if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {

        Log.d ("orientation", "Orientation: LandScape")
    
        width = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenHeight ()
        height = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenWidth ()
        
        // call cpp function
        OrientationChanged (pInstructionSetIndex, width, height)
    }
}
}

if (mOrientationListener.canDetectOrientation ()) {

mOrientationListener.enable ()
}
```

2)TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenHeight ()

```
@JvmStatic
public fun GetScreenHeight (): Int
{
    val metric: WindowMetrics
    val insets: Insets                         // An Insets instance holds four integer offsets which describe changes to the four edges of a Rectangle.
    val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics
    val height: Int
    val insetsHeight: Int
    val context: Context?
     val activity: Activity

context = TWProcessStates.GetMainActivityContext ()

activity = context as Activity

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

    // Code for API level 30 and higher

    metric = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
    insets = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility (WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() or WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout ())

    insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom

    Log.d ("orientation_height", "${insets.right}, ${insets.left}, ${insets.top}, ${insets.bottom}")

    height = metric.bounds.height () - insetsHeight

} else {

    // Code for API level 29 and lower

    displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics ()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics (displayMetrics)

    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
}

Log.d ("orientation_height", "Inside TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid::GetScreenHeight Height: $height")
return height
}
```

I'm getting Portrait mode's height and width when the orientation is Landscape and vice versa, as shown in the below logs:
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: what is your API level?

Comment: Can you share your `OrientationEventListener` whole class code?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakenly assigned width to Height function. You have written this:

```
width = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenHeight ()
```

It should be:

```
height = TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid.GetScreenHeight ()
```

and vice versa

Comment: Oh Actually, I flipped the height and width later to get it working, but forgot to switch it back before posting my bad. The problem is still there, have edited my mistake in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this inside MainActivity:

```
    private var orientationListener: OrientationEventListener? = null
    lateinit private var context: Context

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        context = this
        orientationListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                Log.d("orientation", "$orientation")
                if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {
                    Log.d("orientation", "Orientation: Portrait")
                    getScreenHeight(context)
                    orientationListener?.disable()
                } else if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
                    Log.d("orientation", "Orientation: LandScape")
                    getScreenHeight(context)
                    orientationListener?.disable()
                }
            }
        }
        if (orientationListener?.canDetectOrientation() == true) {
            orientationListener?.enable()
        }
    }

    private fun getScreenHeight(context: Context){
        val metric: WindowMetrics
        val insets: Insets                         // An Insets instance holds four integer offsets which describe changes to the four edges of a Rectangle.
        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics
        val height: Int
        val width: Int
        val insetsHeight: Int
        val insetsWidth: Int
        val activity: Activity
        activity = context as Activity
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            // Code for API level 30 and higher

            metric = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
            insets = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility (
                WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() or WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout ())

            insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom
            insetsWidth = insets.left + insets.right
            Log.d ("orientation", "${insets.right}, ${insets.left}, ${insets.top}, ${insets.bottom}")

            height = metric.bounds.height () - insetsHeight
            width = metric.bounds.width() - insetsWidth

        } else {

            // Code for API level 29 and lower

            displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics ()
            activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics (displayMetrics)

            height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
            width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        }

        Log.d ("orientation", "Inside TWOSScreenAspectsAndroid::GetScreenHeight Height: $height $width")
    }
```

This is working fine for me, what I found was that whenever we rotate device application will recreate the MainActivity and it will register the `orientationListener` again. So i was getting multiple times `onOrientationChanged` and each time it was giving me wrong value except the last time. Hence i added this to get fresh value everytime.

```
orientationListener?.disable()
```

Hope this helps!!